# Vaadin 23 behind Traefik reverse proxy

Tags: vaadin, traefik

I'm looking for an example of Traefik toml config file to serve a newly created Vaadin app. My current config is :

```
[http]
    # Add the router
    [http.routers]
        [http.routers.esus]
            rule = "Host(`app.acme.com`)"
            service = "esus"
            entrypoints = ["web","websecure"]
            passHostHeader = true
        [http.routers.esus.tls]
            certResolver = "letsencrypt"


    # Add the service
    [http.services]
        [http.services.esus.loadbalancer]
            [[http.services.esus.loadbalancer.servers]]
                url = "http://srvdock01:8086"
```

With that, I've got a blank screen. I suppose that it is due to header forward configuration or maybe websocket.

Some help would be really appreciated.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Please add the logs from your browsers dev-console and whatever logs you
have from your proxy.

Comment: I looks like you are running Docker. Are you running Traefik also in docker? If yes then you don't need to configure it in toml but as labels when you start the Docker Container